# After the Enter key, the function and useEffect Hook are called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an input field which should start a search when I press Enter. To do this, the search value is sent as a parameter using axios. So far all good. When the page is initially loaded, the useEffect hook is called and all articles appear. If I then start a search, the searchByName() function is called first and then the useEffect Hook is called again after setProducts(). So I have two calls. If I then press the Enter key again in the input field, searchByName() is called and ends. So no useEffect is called here, which is actually what we want it to be. So how can I change this so that the first press of enter will call ONLY searchByName() WITHOUT the useEffect hook?

```
const searchByName = async (e) => {
if (e.key === "Enter") {
  if (search !== "") {
    await axiosInstance.get(`products/search?q=${search}`).then((res) => {
      setProducts(res.data);
    });
  } else {
    ...
  }
 }
};

useEffect(() => {
 loadProducts();
}, [page]);


const loadProducts = async () => {
 await axiosInstance.get(`products/${page}`).then((res) => {
  setProducts((prev) => [...prev, ...res.data]);
 });
};


...

<input onKeyDown={searchByName} placeholder="Search..."  ... ></input>
```

Comment: wrap your `loadProducts()` in a if check where you can check if your array has changed

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what the page state variable, passed as a dependency, does, but it appears to be the cause of the useEffect re-rendering. Check if any unintentional state changes are occurring. If this is the intended behavior, you can simply declare and use a boolean state variable to keep track of the input keydown.

```js
 const YourComponent = ()=>{
const [enterKeyPressed, setEnterKeyPressed] =useState(false)
const searchByName =  (e) => {
if (e.key === "Enter") {
  if (search !== "") {
setEnterKeyPressed(true)

 axiosInstance.get(`products/search?q=${search}`).then((res) => {
      setProducts(res.data);
    });
  } else {
    ...
  }
 }
};

useEffect(() => {
if(enterKeyPressed)  loadProducts()
else setEnterKeyPressed(false)

}, [page]);


const loadProducts =  () => {
  axiosInstance.get(`products/${page}`).then((res) => {
  setProducts((prev) => [...prev, ...res.data]);
 });
};


...

return <input onKeyDown={searchByName} placeholder="Search..."  ... ></input>


}
```

PS: You should either use async/await or .then, don't mix them.